# Codeigniter: Can't pass data from controller to view, But my friend can

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have been using codeigniter for a few months now and suddenly, it will not let me pass any sort of information to my view. It loads the proper view for a fact but none of my variables can be echoed out, and if i do I always get NULL. However when my coworker does it, he sees the variables just fine. We share the same repository. Any ideas? I am currently using the messages method

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class App_loader extends CI_Controller {
public $data = array();

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function dashboard() {
    $this -> load -> view ('apps/dashboard/index');
}

public function appstore() {
    $this -> load -> view ('apps/appstore/index');
}

public function calendar() {
    $this -> load -> view ('apps/calendar/index');
}

public function messages() {
    $this->data["name"] = "Vincent";
    $this->load->view('apps/messages/index',$this->data);
}

public function profile() {
    $this -> load -> view ('apps/profile/index');
}

public function vendors() {
    $this -> load -> view ('apps/vendors/index');
}

public function settings() {
    $this -> load -> view ('settings');
}   
}
```

all I have in my view is a die statement die($name); and some html. and I get NULL. (yes it is surrounded by the proper php tags.
Has anybody seen anything like this before?

Comment: Currently using MAMP PRO on Mac OS X 10_8_2

Comment: Probably some issues when accessing the global var. Have you tried just setting `$data` locally and then throwing it to the view?

Comment: put public $data = array(); inside function __construct() and try

Comment: yes I have tried setting it locally but to no avail. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: $data = array('name' => "Vincent");
$this->load->view('apps/messages/index',$data);

this wont even work..

Comment: reinstall MAMP and CI and copy your public folders to the new install. If you and your coworker are using identical copies of the software something has corrupted in your install. There isn't any basic setting or config that would stop what you're doing from working that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to use **$this** keyword for variable.You can simply use like this:

```
$data['name'] = 'Vincent';
$this->load->view('apps/messages/index',$data);
```

and in your view you can get value of name just using by **$name**

```
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use normal data array like:

```
 $data=array(); 
 $data["name"] = "Vincent";
 $this->load->view('apps/messages/index',$data);
```

not like:

```
$this->data["name"] = "Vincent";
$this->load->view('apps/messages/index',$this->data);

if used like this you have to put 

$data = array(); in constructor
```

That's it!